# How to show tweets with tweepy on the pyramid framework?

Tags: python, django, twitter, pyramid, tweepy

i have the next code:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
import tweepy

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = "" 

def twitterfeed():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    statuses = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_timeline).items(20)
    for status in statuses:
        return list(str(status.text))
```

this twitterfeed() method is working on the bash/console, and shows the latest tweets of me and my subscribers. But when i want to show this tweets on the page:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('hello', '{name}')
    config.add_view(twitterfeed(), route_name='hello')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

it shows me `pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationExecutionError: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'list' object has no attribute '__module__'
  in:
  Line 24` error

how can i fix it? if you have working example from django, it can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register the *function*, not the result of the function:

```
config.add_view(twitterfeed, route_name='hello')
```

otherwise you are trying to register the list returned by `twitterfeed` as a view instead.

Note that your function needs to accept a `request` parameter too; and it'll have to return a response object too. Change it to:

```
from pyramid.response import Response

def twitterfeed(request):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    statuses =  tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_timeline).items(20)

    return Response('\n'.join([s.text.encode('utf8') for s in statuses]))
```

I've taken the liberty of encoding the tweets to UTF8 instead of leaving it up to Python to pick a default encoding for them (which will lead to UnicodeEncodeError exceptions if there are any international characters in your tweets).

You really want to read up on [pyramid views](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html) before you continue.

As an aside, your command-line version returned only *first* tweet as a list of individual characters (`return list(str(status.text))`).

Comment: and now it shows me error: `ValueError: Could not convert return value of the view callable function __main__.twitterfeed into a response object. The value returned was ('"', '\xd0', '\x93', '\xd0', '\xbe', '\xd0', '\xb2', '\xd0', '\xb5', '\xd1', '\x80', '\xd0', '\xbb', '\xd0', '\xb0', '"', ' ', '\xd0', '\xbf', '\xd1', '\x80', '\xd0', '\xbe', '\xd0', '\xb3', '\xd1', '\x80', '\xd0', '\xb0', '\xd0', '\xbb', '\xd0', '\xb0', ' ', '\xd1', '\x84', '\xd1'`

Comment: thank you!!!! it works! maybe you know some libraries like tweepy, but for facebook and google+ ???
i want a simplisity as with tweepy

Comment: @yakudza_m: Sorry, no idea.